# Inheritance from the base of a base class

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ here.

I'm learning more about inheriting and classes but I'm having the following issue:

```
class A
{
public:
   std::vector<int> vect1;
};

class B : A
{
public:
   int x, y;
};

class C : B
{
   c()
   {
      x=10;
      y=30;
      vect1.pushback(44);
   }
};
```

why cant i access vect1 from the class C? how can i achieve this?

i also tried:

```
class C : B, A {...}
```

but then it said vect1 is ambiguous (or something like that). im using visual studios.

thank you.

Comment: You can't call functions like `vect1.push_back` outside of (member) functions

Comment: If you are in the early stages of learning, it's best to pick up [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). C++ is best learned in a structured manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get access from derived to base class you should do both:

- public inheritance
- protected declaration

like the following:

```
#include <vector>

class A
{
protected:
   std::vector<int> vect1;
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
   int x, y;
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    C(){
       x=10;
       y=30;
       vect1.push_back(44);
    }
};
```

Comment: Exactly right. Extra detail for @CPPApprentice: default inheritance is private. So B derives privately from A, meaning it doesn't expose publicly anything that A exposed.

Comment: _Default inheritance **for classes introduced with the `class` keyword** is private_. It is public for `struct`.

Comment: @YSC Added the word `class`

Comment: @SHR I was refering to jwismar comment ^^ "base class" apply for classes introduced with `class` or `struct` ;) Not a bad edit though.

Answer (score 5):

> why cant i access vect1 from the class C?

Because `vect1` has private access. Sub classes can not access private members of a base class. They can only access protected or public members.

Furthermore, `A` is a private base of `B`, so sub classes of `B` have no access to it. Only protected or public bases are accessible to grand children.

The default access specifier of classes defined with the `class` keyword is private (The default is public for classes defined with the keyword `struct`). To declare a base with another access specifier, you can put the access specifier keyword right before each base in the declaration:

```
class B : protected A
{
    // ...
};
```

To declare members with another access specifier:

```
class A
{
protected:
   std::vector<int> vect1;
};
```